# How to display an image that I uploaded to a folder in a server? I am using php and mysql, in the data base is saved just the name of the picture

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
$target = "logo/";
$target = $target.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$logo = $_FILES['file']['name'];


$sqlimg = "UPDATE usuarios SET rutaimg = '$logo' WHERE user_name ='$_SESSION[username]'";
mysqli_query($con,$sqlimg);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    echo "The file".basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])."Was uploaded";
} else {
    echo "The picture wasnt uploaded";
}
```

Comment: `<img src="/path/to/image/on/server.jpg">`. it's just an image. you display it like any other image, once you figure out what the appropriate url for it would be. And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Thanks @Marc B, check this, it suppose to be a session page, so I need to display the image (a dinamyc way) that the user choose  as logo

Comment: You should save the location of the image (`http://mydomain.example/images/x/y/z.png`) in the database that way you can simply output the image location in to the image `src` as @MarcB suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had an error in my code, so now I can save all the location and the name of the image, both in the same field. So I did a select for tjhe image and put it in a array. the code to show the image is this         echo "<img src=logo/<?php echo $row[file_name]?>";  But it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks all of you, finally I did , Below is how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi As you said that you have already uploaded your image and now want to show same. In this case you should use  tag with src being the `path/to/imagefolder/name of image stored in db`

like you have fetched your data for a perticular user

```
 <table  border="1">
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
      ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['password'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
            <td><img src="logo/<?php echo $row['file_name']?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
     }
     ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: It is necesary to put the image into the <tr> and <td> tags? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try jquery

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#inputFile").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dave17/m2oum2su/

i hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

include ("conexion.php");

$showimg = "SELECT rutaimg FROM usuarios  WHERE user_name='$_SESSION[username]'";

$result3= mysqli_query($connection, $showimg);

$file_path = "localhost/phplogin/";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result3)>0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))

{

```
$src= $row['rutaimg'];
```

}

}

```
?>

<img src="<?php echo $src; ?>">
```